# What's the charset of text returned by InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstreamreader

I read a UTF-8 file by:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

I would like to know what's the charset of returned `String` after I invoke `br.readLine()`?

Eclipse on my Computer uses "GBK" as default charset.

Comment: Why are you asking this? Do you have problems with reading it or with displaying the read characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the file is been read using a charset of UTF-8 as you told the `InputStreamReader` to do so. The underlying bytes of the file content are been interpreted using UTF-8. The `readLine()` method returns a `String` which stores the characters internally in Java's own UTF-16 charset.

What happens thereafter is fully dependent on what you're doing with this `String`. If you're writing it back to a file using a `Writer` without specifying the charset, then the platform's default will be used. If you're displaying it to the stdout, then the stdout's default charset will be used which is dependent on the runtime environment (command console? IDE? etc). If you're saving it in a database, then it's dependent on the JDBC driver configuration and/or the DB table encoding. Etcetera.

Apparently you're printing it to stdout in Eclipse's console by `System.out.println()`. In that case, the GBK charset will be used to display the characters. That would malform any originally read UTF-8 characters which are not covered by GBK. You'd need to configure Eclipse to use UTF-8 as text file encoding. That can be done by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding*.

Answer (score 1):

All Strings in Java are [represented as UTF-16](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). When you read characters in, the encoding you specify is used to convert them to UTF-16. When you write them out, you'll choose another encoding to write it in, either implicitly or explicitly, and the characters will be converted from UTF-16 to whatever you chose.

Answer (score 0):

It is represented as Java chars which are 16-bit Unicode.

Comment: Remember that UTF-8 has no problem storing all Unicode, so one UTF-8 character may be two 16-bit "char units".  A java `char` cannot hold a Unicode character.  It takes a string, with ugly surrogates and all.